# Updating a CSS style globally with variable in scope

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently building an app that has the option to change the theme. A theme in this instance, simply consists of changing the color of a few key elements in the app.

So currently, on all elements that require the theme color, I have given them the css class `has-main-color`.

In the controller, I get their desired color from the web service and set it to the scope as `$scope.mainColor = color;`.

All of this works fine, but the problem I'm getting is that I can't find a suitable method of applying this color to the `has-main-color` class.

Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
<style>
    .has-main-color {
        color: {{mainColor}}
    }
</style>
```

As you could probably guess, this doesn't work so well.

So what would be the best approach to solve this problem using AngularJS?

Comment: styles inside the <style></style> get applied only once. So changing the content inside of it dynamically doesnt help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the documentation page for [ngStyle](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle). It has almost exactly what you want.

```
<input type="button" value="set" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```

Comment: I've done a bit of research into ng-style, and it turns out this is exactly what I need. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: @Ryan,  will it work if I receive the css styles from my Drupal APIs? Suppose i have an app for different group of people an dbased on that user's branding, i need to change, css color, font etc.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can use a `class` to do this, however try this

```
<div ng-app="test-app" ng-controller="MyController" theme-wrapper="{{mainColor}}">
    <div class="has-main-color">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div class="has-main-color">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div class="has-main-color">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="color('red')" />
    <input type="button" value="Green" ng-click="color('green')" />
    <input type="button" value="Blue" ng-click="color('blue')" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){
    $scope.mainColor = 'grey';
    $scope.color = function(color) {
        $scope.mainColor = color;
    }
});

app.directive('themeWrapper', function(){
    var counter = 0, regex = /^theme-wrapper-\d+$/;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            attrs.$observe('themeWrapper', function(value){
                var className = 'theme-wrapper-' + (counter++);
                $('<style>.' + className + ' .has-main-color{color: ' + value + ';}</style>').appendTo('head');

                var classes = elm.attr('class').split(' ');
                angular.forEach(classes, function(v, i){
                    if(regex.test(v)) {
                        elm.removeClass(v);
                    }
                });

                elm.addClass(className);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cbZK5/2/)

Another easy fix

```
<div ng-app="test-app" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div style="color: {{mainColor}}">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div style="color: {{mainColor}}">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div style="color: {{mainColor}}">Top1</div>
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Red" ng-click="color('red')" />
    <input type="button" value="Green" ng-click="color('green')" />
    <input type="button" value="Blue" ng-click="color('blue')" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){
    $scope.mainColor = 'grey';
    $scope.color = function(color) {
        $scope.mainColor = color;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cbZK5/)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone would like to use your original approach, I came across the same problem today and threw together a (tiny!) directive for style which allows for angular expressions inside inline style sheets.

https://github.com/deanmcpherson/angular-inline-style

Allows for

```
body { background-color: {{bgColor}}; }
```

With bg color attached to the appropriate scope.

Comment: Heh, nice work! For the last 3+ months I've been doing the same thing so it might be worth a look-see: [ngCss](http://opensourcetaekwondo.com/ngcss) / [on GitHub](https://github.com/campbeln/ngCss). The issue I see with yours is needing to be within a scope for it to work (so either having the `ng-controller` on the HTML tag or having the STYLE in-line). But then again, yours is 13 lines of code while mine has recently crept past 650 lines ;)

Comment: @deanmcpherson,  
Simple and clean!  Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Found this which does not require a custom directive.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29309120/3291253