# Angular - How to use CSS styles (background image src) from JSON?

Tags: html, css, angular

In Angular, each of these elements is going to have different background images.  I just need to use the `"background"` value coming out of JSON as the source of the background image, for each of these `.card`s.  I also need other CSS styles (styles, not class names) from JSON, including background-position, etc.

For instance, this is the JSON:

```json
{
  "title": "Card Number One",
  "background": "https://www. fakeURL .com/img-one.jpg",
  "background-size": "270%";
  "background-position": "-68px -6px";
}
```

Maybe I can dynamically add these classes with attr binding or something?  I have access to the JSON so I can change anything I need to.

The JSON above would be converted into CSS styles as if it were in CSS like this:

```css
.card {
  background: url(https://www. fakeURL .com/img-one.jpg);
  background-size: 270%;
  background-position: -68px -6px;
}
```

The HTML is basic and can be whatever is needed, but right now it's a Card component within an `*ngFor`:

```html
<div class="card-slot" *ngFor="let cardId of cards">
  <app-card [card]="getCard(cardId)"></app-card>
</div>
```

Thanks!  :)

Comment: what is this getCard(cardId)? use getClass attribute to the card element

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326498/how-to-set-angular-json-model-into-css

Comment: @Gopal - getCard() is a method that takes in the ID and fetches/gathers the rest of the card data.  This way `cards` is just an array of numbers yet the whole card data object gets passed into `[card]` this way.  Pretty handy once I learned it.