# Ionic 2 checkbox background colour without using css. Read the colour from injection/mock data

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I am about to make checkbox background color without using CSS as I want it to be dynamic. Is there any way I could do that?

```
                 <ion-row >

                    <ion-col text-center *ngFor="let color of color_row1">

                        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="color.checked" ngClass="{{color.colorName}}" color="{{color.colorName}}" (click)="updateSelection(color.colorId,color.colorName)" ></ion-checkbox>

                    </ion-col>

                </ion-row>
```

color.colorName is read from variable.scss files which is not dynamic. I am thinking of 2 ways of doing this whether I can inject data service into SCSS files or I could change the colour of checkbox in html without using CSS but could not find any way to do that. Could anybody help me pls?

Comment: Take a look at NgStyle, a directive which allows you to add style to an element. More info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-sass-variable-dynamically/31792) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090877/dynamic-classname-inside-ngclass-in-angular-2), none of your ways are work. But you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918458/dynamically-change-a-css-class-properties-with-angularjs) approach. It add the styles to the page. I think you must change this:

```
.checkbox-md-primary .checkbox-checked {
    border-color: #387ef5;
    background-color: #387ef5;
 }
```